# How does (or will) the Jobs tab on the Ask Different site work?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Currently the jobs url that's live on the site navigation (and meta) resolves as a 404:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/jobs

Is this an expansion of the Stack Overflows careers or something different?

Comment: Though there is this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/bringing-jobs-to-stack-overflow/

Answer (score 6):

That was my fault.  I removed an if check that was very important.  It has been reverted.

Comment: dang and thanks